# Not able to convert cassandra blob/bytes string to integer

Tags: python, cassandra, cqlsh, cqlengine

I have a column-family/table in cassandra-3.0.6 which has a column named "value" which is defined as a blob data type.

CQLSH query `select * from table limit 2;` returns me:

> id   | name  | value
>
> id_001 | john  | 0x010000000000000000
>
> id_002 | terry | 0x044097a80000000000

If I read this value using cqlengine(Datastax Python Driver), I get the output something like:

> {'id':'id_001', 'name':'john', 'value': '\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'}
>
> {'id':'id_002', 'name':'terry', 'value': '\x04@\x97\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'}

Ideally the values in the "value" field are `0` and `1514` for `row1` and `row2` resp.

However, I am not sure how I can convert the "value" field values extracted using cqlengine to `0` and `1514`. I tried few methods like `ord()`, `decode()`, etc but nothing worked. :(

**Questions:**

1. What is this format?
   `'\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'` or
   `'\x04@\x97\xa8\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`?
2. How I can convert these arbitrary values to `0` and `1514`?

NOTE: I am using python 2.7.9 on Linux

Any help or pointers would be useful.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

1. Blob will be converted to a byte array in Python if you read it directly. That looks like a byte array containing the Hex value of the blob.
2. One way is to explicitly do the conversion in your query.

   `select id, name, blobasint(value) from table limit 3`

   There should be a conversion method with the Python driver as well.